# I am trying to make an equation calculator that finds out how long it will take for a satellite(not necessarily a man made one) around a radius

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ and my cousin is going to major in astronomy so he tasked me with creating a calculator to do this equation t=sqrt(4*pi*pi*r*r*r/g*m). Looks easy enough Right? That's exactly what I thought until I tried it. The oody variables below are just for trying to debug it. For one thing a variable is definitely not going to contain such a long variable another thing is the answer must be divided by 86,400 and if its such a long decimal the computer thinks that it is 0 and it gives a integer division by 0 error for another thing if m is not big enough then it will give a division by 0 error and I am not sure how to fix it. If someone could just give me a little help it would greatly be appreciated.

```
// OTM.cpp A very interesting program!
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>


using namespace std;

long double days(int m, int r, int g, int pi);

int main()
{
SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("Orbit Time Of The A Satelite 1.0"));
long double t = 0;
long double q = 0;
const long double g = 0.000000000066726;
long float m = 0;
long float r = 0;
double pi = M_PI;

cout << "Hello welcome to OTM!" << endl;

cout << "What is the mass of the host?" << endl;
cout << "ENTER HERE: " << flush;
cin >> m;

cout << "" << endl;

cout << "What is the radius of the object?" << endl;
cout << "ENTER HERE: " << flush;
cin >> r;

cout << "" << endl;
cout << pi << endl;
cout << "The object is going " << days(m, r, g, pi) << " meters per second"     << endl;
cout << t << endl;
long double roody = pi * pi;
long double goody = roody * 4;
long double loody = r * r * r;
long double moody = loody * goody;
long double soody = m * g;
long double voody = soody / moody;
cout << roody << endl;
cout << goody << endl;
cout << loody << endl;
cout << moody << endl;
cout << soody << endl;
cout << voody << endl;

return 0;
}

 long double days(int m, int r, int g, int pi) {

long double t = sqrt(4 * (pi*pi) * (r*r*r) / (m * g));

long double q = t / 86400;

return t;


}
```

Comment: Off topic recommendation: Take a bit more care in the naming of variables. `roody` tells the reader absolutely nothing about the purpose of the variable, and that makes debugging more difficult for everyone. Here the declaration, assignment, and use are all close together, but this will not always be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested the code, but surely you did **not** want to use `int`s here for the calculation?

Change:

```
 long double days(int m, int r, int g, int pi)
```

to either `float` or `double` depending on your needs:

```
 long double days(double m, double r, double g, double pi)
```

The main thing you should understand is what happens when you assign a variable of type `float` or `double` to a variable of type `int`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I combed through this code for hours and can not believe I just overlooked this thanks again!